# cannot have a different default for font's height with emacs daemon

Tags: faces, fonts

Following an article called [Emacs, fonts and fontsets](https://idiocy.org/emacs-fonts-and-fontsets.html) I was revising my font setup. I ended with the following code:

```
(defun font-exists-p (font)
  "Comprueba si una tipografía existe. Sacado de https://redd.it/1xe7vr"
  (if (member font (font-family-list))
      t
    nil))

(defun font-pt-to-height (pt)
  "Transforma una altura en puntos (pt) a altura de face-attribute."
  ;; el valor es de 1/10pt, por tanto 100 seria equivalente a 10pt, etc.
  (* pt 10))

(defun font-setup (frame)
  ;; tipografia por defecto
  (cond ((font-exists-p "Fira Code")
         (set-face-attribute 'default frame :family "Monospace" :height (font-pt-to-height 13) :font "Fira Code")))
  (cond ((font-exists-p "Apple Color Emoji")
         (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Apple Color Emoji") frame 'prepend))
        ((font-exists-p "Symbola")
         (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :size 20 :name "Symbola") frame 'prepend))))

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'font-setup t)
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook (lambda () (font-setup nil)))
```

but for some reason Emacs ran as a daemon keeps the defaults, see this screenshot:

[image: customize-face for 'default showing the font to be DejaVu Sans Mono]

If I manually run `(font-setup nil)` the default face change to what I want which is Fira Code (`customize-face` confirms to me the change to the default face happened)

I would like for my font setup configuration to be applied on the first frame and all the following frames.

Comment: emacs server is sometimes started before other services (i.e. xft-font-server) are up, so please check if your calls to `font-exists-p` fails. You could do that by inserting some `(message ..)` calls and later looking at `*Messages* `buffer.

Comment: @jue I made a small modification to that function and a warning is issued when (font-family-list) returns a ["falsy" value](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Truth-_0026-Falsehood.html) and indeed the function is called. Maybe this is a matter of wrapping things inside a `with-eval-after-load` or something

Comment: Surely it is possible to fix that from within emacs, but a clean solution would start emacs server **after** the required OS services are up. This depends on your operating system, you didn't specify your used one.

Comment: From your profile, I suspect that your init system is `systemd`, so have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21830670/systemd-start-service-after-specific-service/21832006

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this issue [has affected many users over the years](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25221960/2020214), I implemented this workaround:

```
(defun fc-list ()
  "Genera una lista de tipografías disponibles usando fc-list"
  (if (executable-find "fc-list")
      (split-string (shell-command-to-string "fc-list --format='%{family[0]}\n' | sort | uniq") "\n")
    (progn
      (warn "fc-list command is not available")
      nil)))
```

and modified my font-exists-p function as following:

```
(defun font-exists-p (font)
  "Comprueba si una tipografía existe. Código parcialmente sacado de https://redd.it/1xe7vr"
  (let ((font-list (or (font-family-list) (fc-list))))
    (if (member font font-list)
        t
      nil)))
```

and then glue it all together:

```
(defun font-setup (&optional frame)
  (cond ((font-exists-p "Fira Code")
         (set-face-attribute 'default frame :height (font-pt-to-height 13) :font "Fira Code")))
  (cond ((font-exists-p "Apple Color Emoji")
         (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :family "Apple Color Emoji") frame 'prepend))
        ((font-exists-p "Symbola")
         (set-fontset-font t 'symbol (font-spec :size 20 :name "Symbola") frame 'prepend))))

(defun font-setup-frame (frame)
  "configura la tipografía por cada nuevo marco FRAME creado."
  (select-frame frame)
  (when (display-graphic-p)
    (font-setup frame)))

(if (daemonp)
    (add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'font-setup-frame)
  (font-setup))
```